# How can I overcome discrete nature of a numerical algorithm that is currently skipping over a certain real number inside a loop?

Tags: php, algorithm, discrete-mathematics

I have a fairly complex algorithm that performs a search where I use a `$search` variable in some range [0.25 to 1.75].

Based on the algorithm there is an "interesting" thing happens when the `$search` is exactly 1, because it hits a configuration of variables that is *sometimes* (but not always) most favorable.  Some of the code depends on `$search` being exactly 1 to produce that most favorable outcome.

More specifically, there is usually some specific value within the search range, which produces most favorable outcome, but the way my algorithm is laid out, that specific value is most often skipped over.  Here I lay out example when that specific value (based on other inputs and configuration), happens to be exactly 1..

**The Problem**

Mathematically speaking if `$search` was continuous rather than discreet, I wouldn't have this problem.  My problem is trying to converge on most favorable variable configuration using discrete mathematics.  The issue here is the algorithm.  Secondary issue to watch out for as well is floating point arithmetic, but I do not believe that is the issue here just yet.

**Basic Loop:**

```php
$maxPowerOut = 0 ; 
for ($increment = 0; $increment <= 500; $increment ++)
{
    //vars computed elsewhere, i.e:
    //MIN = 0.24651533;
    //STEP = 0.00196969
    $search = MIN + STEP * $increment;

    //compute several coefficients (returns an array)
    $coeff = $this->coefficient($search);  

    //design is a complex library function 
    list($a, $b) = $this->design($coeff); 

    $powerOut = $a * $b;

    //keep track of max power (and other params, not shown)
    if ($powerOut > $maxPowerOut)
        $maxPowerOut = $PowerOut;
}

//currently prints 899.993 instead of 900 as should be expected
print "Max Power is $maxPowerOut";
```

Naturally, `$search` is almost never 1 exactly.  It goes like this:

- 0.99569478115682
- 0.99866447159913
- 1.0016341620414
- 1.0046038524837
- 1.0075735429261
- ...

Note how 1 is skipped over in above loop.  For the sake of argument let's say most favorable position happens at 1.003000.  That value (1.003000) would be skipped over as well.

**Question**

How can I improve, restructure, rethink, reorganize, rewrite my loop to avoid this type of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple improvement might be to use an iterative approach:

In your current loop you search say 500 values in the interval [0.25, 1.75]. Let's say you can narrow down the optimum to the much smaller interval [0.995, 1.007] in this way. Then again divide this interval into say 500 values and repeat your loop. Repeat until you reach the desired precision.

Mathematically, you want to find the maximum within a given interval of a function `f: search -> power` that computes some `power` value for a given `search` parameter. Note that this is generally easier the smoother your function `f` is. To get a feeling for what `f` might look like, you can plot the function based on the values you computed in your loop.

If your function is well-behaved and is say unimodal (has only one "hump"), then for instance a simple [golden section search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search) would be effective.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick JavaScript snippet / pseudo code, to help solve your problem. Basically your function should recursively call itself if you find that the deltas / slope have toggled from positive to negative.

```
function findMax(low, high) {
    var maxOut = Number.MIN_VALUE;
    // Calculate a step based on the low and high
    // Using a power of 2 since the floating point numbers are represented by binary
    var step = Math.abs((high - low) / 128);
    // we'll be tracking the deltas of two test values
    var prevDelta;
    var delta;
    // loop and check two values at a time
    for(var i=low; i<=(high - step); i+=step) {
        // coef ...
        // design ...
        // for testing
        var out1 = Math.cos(i);
        var out2 = Math.cos(i + step);
        // update the max
        if(out1 > maxOut) maxOut = out1;
        if(out2 > maxOut) maxOut = out2;
        // calc delta
        delta = out2 - out1;
        if(prevDelta !== undefined) {
            // If one delta is going up and
            // another is going down...
            // Recursively call the function
            if(prevDelta > 0 && delta < 0) {
                var out3 = findMax(i - step, i + step);
                // update the max
                if(out3 > maxOut) maxOut = out3;
            }
        }
        prevDelta = delta;
    }
    return maxOut;
}
alert(findMax(-0.5, 0.5)); // returns 1
```

Here's the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hw5f2o1s/

The above approach won't work if the maximum lies between your initial low and low + step, because the recursion is triggered by reaching a peak then going down from it. If this happens you may have to make the *step* variable smaller by increasing the power of two dividing *(high - low)*.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers have limited precision (they're discreet), expect deviations.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

You can try the [arbitrary precision extension](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php)

Answer (score 0):

**Current direction**

Number `1.0` seems to be of importance, perhaps representing `default`.  Rework the code to include `1.0` as part of the `$search`, either injecting it as part of the same loop or as a separate iteration.